# Respuestas en punteros erroneas C

Tags: c

El ejercicio trata de resolver una ecuación de segundo grado y en función de lo que dé, los punteros recibirán una cosa u otra. Los primeros dos casos no me dan problema pero cuando hago la prueba del tercer y el cuarto los punteros reciben algo que no he programado.

Por ejemplo cuando pongo a y b a cero se supone la ecuación no tiene solución y por tanto `px1` y `px2` que son punteros deben dar 0.000 y 0.000 sin embargo me dan -nan y -nan. En el cuarto caso que sucede cuando la ecuación es de primer grado es decir que `a` es cero me debería devolver la ecuación de primer grado resuelta en `px1` y -nan en px2. Por el contrario me devuelve -nan -inf.

He probado a cambiar los `else if` por si no entraban, pero nada, llevo varias horas y no se me ocurre nada.

Por si lo necesitáis el primer caso es si el resultado de la ecuación es real se almacenan ambos resultados en los dos punteros. El segundo caso es si hay solución imaginaria, la parte real se pone en `px1` y la imaginaria en `px2`.

Adjunto la parte de la función, el `main` tan solo tiene los `scanf` y `print` para poder usarla.

```
    int resolver(double a , double b, double c, double* px1, double* px2){


    if((pow(b,2) - 4* a * c )>= 0){
        *px1 = (-b + sqrt(pow(b,2) - 4* a * c))/ (2 * a);
        *px2 = (-b - sqrt(pow(b,2) - 4* a * c))/ (2 * a);
        return 1;
    }else if((pow(b,2) - 4* a * c) < 0){
        *px1 = -b/(2*a);
        *px2 = sqrt(-(pow(b,2) - 4* a * c))/(2*a);
        return 2;
    }else if(a == 0 && b==0){
        *px1 = 0;
        *px2 = 0;
        return 3;
    }else if(a == 0 ){
        *px1 = -c/b;
        *px2 = sqrt(-1.0);
        return 4;
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Significa que entra en un caso anterior donde también se cumple la condición.

Por ejemplo, si `a=0, b=0`, el primer if es:

`(pow(0,2) - 4* 0 * c )>= 0`, que debería ser `(0 - 0) >= 0`, que debería dar `true`.

Tu código funciona perfecto, sólo que se ocupa de otras cosas primero.

Cambia el orden de tus validaciones y aprende a hacer debug de tu código. Así sabrás qué pasa con la ejecución dependiendo de los valores en las variables usadas